# Haskell function which sorts a list of integer lists according to the length of the sublists

Tags: haskell

I have a list:

```
[[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[4],[1,2,5,4],[2,3,1]]
```

I want to sort this list in ascending order and length with respect to sublists

like this:

```
[[4],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,5,4]]
```

I found one solution, but that is not what I want

I found this function:

```
import Data.List

doubleSort :: (Ord a, Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
doubleSort = sortOn sum . map sort
```

But this sorts the list in a way which I dont want:

```
[[1,2],[4],[2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,4,5]]
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want the sublists sorted first by length and then by lexicographic ordering, or just by length (or by length and sum)? Your above example is ambiguous in this respect.

Comment: @hnefatl first it should be sorted by number of elements in an sublist (ascending order), and then by total sum of elements in sublists (ascending order). `[[4],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,5,4]]` like this

Comment: @hnefatl no, it only sorts the list with respect to the sum of elements present in the sublist....see the question, I have written both, what I want and what I get when using `sortOn sum . sortOn length`

Answer (score 2):

`sort{[By,On]}` are stable sorts, so you can simply sort by the secondary critereon and then by the primary one.

```
> :m +Data.List
> sortOn length $ sort [[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[4],[1,2,5,4],[2,3,1]]
[[4],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,5,4]]
```

If it is already sorted lexicographically, then simply `sortOn length` alone will do.

Comment: Think it should be `sortOn sum` instead of `sort`: in the comments OP mentioned it should be sorted by list sum rather than lexicographic.

Comment: Possibly; didn't quite understand the question. But it should be obvious how to generalise that, the crucial point is about stability.

Answer (score 2):

with one `sort`

```
> sortOn (length &&& sum)
```

`&&&` is from Control.Arrow

Comment: That's really beautiful. It could use some explanation though... my go, the idea is to build _tuples_ of length and sum. The tuple `Ord` instance sorts by the _tuple_ elements lexicographically, i.e. `length` has priority.